# What does "no frame of graft" mean in this context?

Tags: idioms, meaning-in-context

> Young Ethan: All right, look. I've gotta tell you something. I'm not
>   17. I only said so that you'd think I was cute and vunerable. I'm actually 30, I have a wife, I have a job, I'm your Congressman.
>   Monica, this is ridiculous, we're great together. We can talk, we make
>   each other laugh, and the sex. Oh, man, okay i have **no frame of graft**,
>   but I thought that was great.
>
> Monica: It was.
>
> Young Ethan: Then, what's the problem?
>
> Monica: Ethan, it's um... it's icky.

Taken from the sitcom *Friends* season 1 episode 22, it's hard for me to understand the meaning of "no frame of graft" in this context.

After searching through the internet, I figured it might not be an idiom or slang.

Anyone share their interpretation with me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No frame of [graft](http://it.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=graft);  no deliberate intention ( scheme) to have sex with you!

> - A long process where one persistently flirts and talks with a girl via text, msn, facebook etc. until you (eventually/rarely) have sex with her.
>
>   - "Joe is a grafting machine! Everytime I see him he's texting some female..."

( Urban Dictionary)

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. I would understand _frame_ quite differently here: it means “I have no frame of reference”, really. Ethan hasn't had sex with anyone else, so when he says the sex was great, he's kind of guessing, ’cause he has nothing to compare it to.

Comment: Play on words...no frame of reference to compare this sexual experience with. You need to finish the answer, Josh!